# Il en est de même

Tags: sens, locutions, en

> Il en est de même des lapins.

Quelle est la fonction de en ici ? Quelle est le sens de la proposition ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La locution *il en est de même*, comme son équivalent *[il en va de même](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29193/quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-il-en-est-de-m%C3%AAme-et-il-en-va-de-m%C3%AAme)*, signifie *La même chose est vraie, s'applique...*.

*En* y fait référence à quelque chose qui a été exprimé précédemment.

---

The idiom *il en est de même*, like its equivalent *[il en va de même](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29193/quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-il-en-est-de-m%C3%AAme-et-il-en-va-de-m%C3%AAme)*
means *The same thing is true, applies*.

*En* refers to something expressed earlier.

Comment: Merci. Donc, la proposition veut dire " la même chose s'applique aux lapins " ?

Comment: C'est possible. Il est difficile de donner la signification précise d'une phrase quand elle est tirée de son contexte.

Comment: Très bien. Merci encore !