# La fonction de « en » dans la phrase « Et comment en serait-il autrement ? »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs, formulation-idiomatique

Je crois que en gros, elle veut dire

> And how would it be otherwise...?

Mais, est-ce que je peux exprimer la même chose sans « en » ? C'est-à-dire, ça sert à quoi exactement dans cette phrase ?  Normalement, « en » est un pronom relatif, mais dans ce cas, je n'arrive pas à trouver le mot auquel il fait référence. Peut-être que c'est idiomatique ?

Si c'est important, voici plus de contexte:

> Je sens bien qu'au-delà de certaines vues partagées et d'une sensibilité identique, nous sommes un des couples les plus mal assortis qu'on puisse imaginer. Il ne supporte pas qu'on puisse penser qu'il est un père déjeunant avec sa fille installée à Berlin.  **Et comment en serait-il autrement**, puisque je préfère m'habiller comme sa fille et ne pas risquer, en faisant preuve d'un peu d'élégance, d'avoir l'air d'une escorte promenant son client ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*En serait-il* (*il en serait*) est un présentatif. Le sujet *il* est impersonnel; il ne correspond à rien de précis. On peut considérer que *en* fait référence à la situation décrite précédemment.

Sans ce *en*, la phrase signifierait:

> And how would **he** be otherwise.

On [retrouve](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29193/quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-il-en-est-de-m%C3%AAme-et-il-en-va-de-m%C3%AAme) ce *en* dans les expressions *il en est de même* et *il en va de même*.

Answer (score 2):

La locution "il en est/était/sera/serait/…" sert à  « marquer  l'état, le point d'aboutissement d'une action, d'un processus » ([être](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/%C3%AAtre?page=1)). Le pronom adverbial neutre  « en » ([Académie](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/%C3%AAtre?page=1), [Bescherelle](https://bescherelle.ca/pronoms-personnels-adverbiaux/)) remplace une idée qui n'est explicite mais qui se dégage de « il est un père déjeunant avec sa fille à Berlin » (« en » n'est donc pas un pronom relatif, bien que cette notion soit très proche) ; cette idée est celle des situations où l'homme en question et sa compagne (le narrateur) se trouvent ensemble en public.

Il y a plusieurs possibilités d'utilisation d'une tournure sans « en ».

1/ Tout d'abord il y a la possibilité d'utiliser la tournure en question en supprimant « en » mais en ajoutant un complément qui « en tient lieu ».

- *Il n'y a pas lieu à mettre « en », lorsque la phrase a un complément qui en tient lieu. ([Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/%C3%AAtre))*
  **exemple (user LPH)** Et comment serait-il autrement **de nos apparitions en public**, puisque je préfère m'habiller comme sa fille et ne pas risquer, en faisant preuve d'un peu d'élégance, d'avoir l'air d'une escorte promenant son client ? (Le complément « de nos apparitions en public » remplace « en »).

2/ Il y a ensuite une possibilité en changeant le pronom « il ».

- Et comment **[ça serait/ça pourrait être]** autrement, puisque je préfère m'habiller comme sa fille et ne pas risquer, en faisant preuve d'un peu d'élégance, d'avoir l'air d'une escorte promenant son client ?

Comment: Comme toujours, merci pour tous les détails!